# How to do DB2-SQL delete top N … in AS400

Tags: sql, db2, fetch, ibm-midrange, delete-row

`SELECT * FROM DB FETCH 100 ROW ONLY`   -> is ok.

`delete  from DB FETCH 100 ROW ONLY` -> why not?

Comment: How is AS400 related to this question?

Answer (score 3):

FETCH FIRST xxx ROWS ONLY

Is basically just a performance shortcut when you don't need a the full results set.  The manual says:

> Specification of the fetch-first-clause in a select-statement makes
>   the result table read-only. A read-only result table must not be
>   referred to in an UPDATE or DELETE statement. The fetch-first-clause
>   cannot appear in a statement containing an UPDATE clause.

This should work

```
DELETE FROM mytbl
WHERE pk IN (SELECT pk FROM mytbl
             FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
            )
```

Comment: What is pk in this example?

Comment: @user4463876 whatever the primary key is for the table.

Comment: thanks, so in most cases simply row ID

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:-

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM DB FETCH 100 ROWS ONLY)
```

**EDIT:-**

You may try this:-

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM "BACKUPLIB/SCDKISLOG3" FETCH 100 ROWS ONLY)
```

Comment: delete from (select * from backuplib/scdkislog3 fetch 100 rows only) try result is...delete from (select * from backuplib/scdkislog3 fetch 100 rows only)
Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: <IDENTIFIER>.

Comment: @user3374083:- Which identifier it is saying as INVALID?

Comment: @user3374083:- Try this:- delete from (select * from "backuplib/scdkislog3" fetch 100 rows only

Comment: delete from (select * from "backuplib/scdkislog3" fetch 100 rows only) Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: <IDENTIFIER>.   "FROM" after ' ( ' not valid command.

Comment: result : Token * was not valid. Valid tokens: <END-OF-STATEMENT>

Comment: @user3374083:- Try this:- DELETE FROM table_name where id in (SELECT id FROM "BACKUPLIB/SCDKISLOG3" FETCH 100 ROWS ONLY)

Answer (score 0):

Use this form:

```
delete from mytable a where rrn(a) in 
(select rrn(b) from mytable b fetch first 100 rows only)
```

The {delete from (select...} form can't be used. A table-function is only valid in a subselect, not a DELETE.